# Partial Fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Given an input of a string, output the partial fraction in string form.

The partial fraction decomposition of a rational fraction of the form \$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\$, where \$f\$ and \$g\$ are polynomials, is its expression as:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=p(x)+\sum_j\frac{f_j(x)}{g_j(x)}$$

In this case \$p\$ is 0, because we assume that the numerator is smaller than the denominator.

#### Input:

In the form of an a list of the coefficients:

```
[[1, 4], [[1,3], [1,3]]]
```

For `(x+4)/(x+3)^2`.

#### Output:

In the form of a list too:

```
[[[1], [1, 3]], [[1], [1, 6, 9]]]
```

For `1/(x+3) + 1/(x+3)^2`.

#### Assumptions

- The power of - `x^` can be of any power greater than 1
- The fractions are **factorised whenever possible**
- You can output the elements of a list or the list itself
- You can take the input as a list or separate elements
- The numerator highest degree is always lower than the denominator highest degree
- You can take the input and output in any order
- The input will not be in a way such that the numerator and denominator have a factor in common
- You can assume all inputs take this form:
  $$\frac{something}{(something)(something)(...)}$$
- Note there can be multiple fractions e.g.:
  $$\frac{x+4}{(x+1)(x-2)(x+3)^2}$$

### Note:

<s>This is **not** as easy as it looks</s> This only gets harder. There are multiple cases to follow:

1. Linear factors

$$\frac{N(x)}{(ax+b)(cx+d)}=\frac{A}{ax+b}+\frac{B}{cx+d}$$

2. Repeated linear factors

$$\frac{N(x)}{(ax+b)^2}=\frac{A}{ax+b}+\frac{B}{(ax+b)^2}$$

3. Quadratic factor (non-factorisable)

$$\frac{N(x)}{(ax+b)(x^2+bx+c)}=\frac{A}{ax+b}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+bx+c}$$

#### Testcases

```
Case 1:
[1,4], [[1,3], [1,2]] -> [[-1], [1,3]], [[2], [1,2]]
```

$$\frac{x+4}{(x+3)(x+2)}=\frac{-1}{x+3}+\frac{2}{x+2}$$

```
Case 2:
[1,4], [[1,3], [1,3]] -> [[1], [1,3]], [[1], [[1,3], [1,3]]]
```

$$\frac{x+4}{(x+3)^2}=\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{(x+3)^2}$$

```
Case 3:
[2,-1,4], [[1,0], [1,0,4]] -> [[1], [1,0]], [[1,-1], [1,0,4]]
```

$$\frac{2x^2-x+4}{x(x^2+4)}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{x-1}{x^2+4}$$

Comment: "It's not as easy as it looks" Well, it doesn't look particularly easy :P

Comment: Are we to assume that the "somethings" in the denominator are no more than second order? Ie. will the denominator always be `[L1, L2, ...]` where Ln is no more than 3 elements?

Comment: I feel like mathematica has a built in for this....

Comment: Could you provide a clearer explanation of the requirements, at the moment it just has a formula with four undefined terms (\$p\$, \$j\$, \$f_j\$, and \$g_j\$) - apart from the test cases I don't see what stops \$p\$ being the input with the sum being zero. What should the denominators (\$g_j\$?) of the terms in the output be? What is \$p\$ and what can we use it for?

Comment: "Input In the form of an entire string"... `[[1, 4], [[1,3], [1,3]]]`.  But the latter appears to be a nested array, not a string.  So is the input a nested array?  Or anything reasonable?

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 I guess https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apart.html?

Comment: @CursorCoercer no, the denominator can be as long as possible :3, and no, it can be higher, but only if the equation cant be factorised which leaves you with the high x power

Comment: Could you provide a test case with a cubic (or higher) un-factorisable term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Mathematica, 124 bytes

```
#~CoefficientList~x&/@{Numerator@#,Denominator@#}&/@List@@Apart[First@#~FromDigits~x/Fold[Times,(#~FromDigits~x&)/@Last@#]]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/35dad498-0c80-4233-8ba2-cddd232ad6bc)

`Apart` does the heavy lifting here. The rest of the code allows it to work on the specified input and output format.

Comment: Hey... you cheated! :3 (nah its fine)

Comment: @DialFrost I felt it was justified seeing as ~96% of the answer is for I/O ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Python3, 1029 bytes:

```py
import itertools as I
E=enumerate
U=lambda x:{len(x)-i:a for i,a in E(x,1)}
def G(v,r=[]):
 if[]==v:yield r;return
 for k in I.product(*[[-1,0,1]for _ in v[0]]):
  N=[a+b for a,b in zip(v[0],k)]
  if N[0]:yield from G(v[1:],r+[N])
  else:yield from G(v[1:],r+[[-1]+N[1:]])
def P(p):
 if[]==p:return{0:1}
 s=U(p[0])
 for e in p[1:]:
  n={}
  for i,a in E(e,1):
   for A in s:n[A+len(e)-i]=n.get(A+len(e)-i,0)+s[A]*a
  s=n
 return s
T=lambda x:P([eval(i)for j,k in x for i in[j]*k])
H=lambda n,N:[1]+[0]*(max(n)-max(N))
def f(n,d):
 S,D,M={*map(str,d)},[],{}
 for i in S:Y=d.count(eval(i));D+=[(i,Y)]+[(i,1)]*(Y>1 and len(S)==1);M[i]=max(Y,M.get(i,0))
 N=U(n);q,O=[[(a,b,t:=T([(j,M[j])for j in{*M}-{a}]+[(a,M[a]-b)]*(M[a]-b>0)),H(N,t))for a,b in D]],[]
 while q:
  a=q.pop(0)
  O+=[a]
  r={}
  for *_,p,o in a:
   for A,B in P([[*p.values()],o]).items():r[A]=r.get(A,0)+B
  if r==N:return[[i[-1],[eval(i[0])]*int(i[1])]for i in a]
  for i in G([j[-1]for j in a]):
   v=[(A,B,C,z)for (A,B,C,_),z in zip(a,i)]
   if v not in O:q+=[v]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNNT@MwEL3nV/hop9OqgT2sUhkJFgQcGlYCDpVlIZe6i0vrGCftFqr@9u5M0tLlwMmeL897b8bhvX4p/enPEHc7twhlrJmrbazLcl4xU7Hb5Epav1zYaGqbPMq5WYwnhq3zzdx6vhZdlxs2LSNzYJjz7IqvIRPbZGKn7JqvIEqlRZ4wN1VaylX@7ux8wuIg2noZfdKUvlLhbS/EcrJ8rnmqVDeDPmSagk8UXKm@bp5hhVSmM27KDIwp9uECpzi8Co0JbsoKtPaNprFcEA6V5RpiRxVaYI6dV/abBGytOwVZmEkkfvNwxB/yFvemn2fbhFXykQdsJloeluAEqiWkXm4w5as2FrWhWOM9J1@Ve3XeIS0taqml7/2xNT96oC86lTrXqcGySqJiLQJWJQ/HYfzmyq7MnDtBD8@gUXTd9sarmun0FVHeHCo8FLlCoog95Quz5l506ShES3rKPUwI6T1cwlBu0oUJvKojOregNBCzw@PsPh/JSe@5XPqa71GIwWVHKu5gJLAJnpnARqOzjBk/YcTtXkiZicFQIWfqPIJhw5wIo5wFKuvF4A3upFIcJw11Lh@44jMYIpuWJjbfpMNtd2O21MVgyOjumFq1tzN8C254AbUQ/23MpdZIImF/X9zcsjcaiJFvvVAG3qf1uEPshnYpHkeYPkGAkqrNcYBwQQ4UX6Whh8yXtuJCQ6lFDz/RAo084uxkbIdKs7xoVzRKWex3SSlHSwf7CdI66dShlg4nJPSnzA2iT@uaqxmVHYTAcLtZK9QdgcEv@Gg4740nAR@H32LANV@FgKyYL2sK3OVvSHuldyFS8ylXGfzQwBSep3RmcIJ/QiTfx0@/xk@ge0zptyl9dGDS7h8)

Comment: there's whitespace in the second to last line: `for (A,B,C...)`

Comment: suggest `O+=[a:=q.pop(0)]`

Comment: also `from itertools import*` saves a byte

Comment: `yield from G(*N[0]and(v[1:],r+[N])or(v[1:],r+[[-1]+N[1:]]))` also works

Comment: and `for A in s:j=A+len(e)-i;n[j]=n.get(j,0)+s[A]*a`

Comment: and `for k in product(*[[-1,0,1]for _ in v[0]]):N=[a+b for a,b in zip(v[0],k)];yield from G(*N[0]and(v[1:],r+[N])or(v[1:],r+[[-1]+N[1:]]))`

Comment: and `O+=[a:=q.pop(0)];r={}`

Comment: and `P([p.values(),o])` also works because `[] != [p.values(),o]` and `enumerate(p.values(),1)` is equivalent to `enumerate([*p.values()],1)`